# how to install Hudson Jython plug-in

Tags: plugins, hudson, jython

Following chapter 18 of Definitive Guide to Jython...

http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/TestingIntegration.html

... it talks about downloading Hudson, which I did, running the war file, which I did, looking at the page at localhost:8080, which I did... but then it says

> Before creating jobs, we will install the Jython plug-in. Click on the
>   Manage Hudson link on the left-hand menu. Then click Manage Plug-ins.
>   Now go to the Available tab. You will see a very long list of plug-ins
>   (we told you this was the greatest Hudson strength!) Find the Jython
>   Plug-in

... I don't know what left-hand menu they mean... and there is no Jython plug-in listed on the page.  Presumably due to Hudson having moved on since the last update to this page of the Jython Book... can anyone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are using Hudson-3.X. You can install this plugin as follows. In the main Hudson page click on `Manage Hudson`.

[image]

Select the option `Manage Plugins`

[image]

Select the tab `Available` followed by the tab `Others`. You will find `Jython Plugin` here.